# Vertical Navbar/Sidebar align elements centered

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, nav, sidebar

I am trying to build a sidebar with centered vertical elements like this design:

[image]

I couldn't figure it out after 2 hours so I decided to ask you guys if somebody could help me since I can't find any good links that can provide helpful information.

I think I am doing something wrong in the following `sidenav` class:

```
.sidenav {
    overflow: auto;
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 200;
    background-color: #16191C;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 100%;
    color: #e1ffff;
}
```

Check [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tdaeh7yu/1/).

Comment: add the `fa-fw` class to the icons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First the a href must be inside the li element..

use flexbox.

```
ul {
 position: fixed; 
 z-index: 1;
 top: auto;
 bottom: auto;
 left: 0;
 /*right: 0;*/
 margin: auto;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 50px;
 display:flex;
 flex-direction:row;
 flex-wrap:wrap;
 justify-content:center;
}

ul li {
  display:block;
  width:100%;
}
```

[Try this updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tdaeh7yu/2/)

OK try this

[with more elements](https://jsfiddle.net/tdaeh7yu/3/)

Comment: doesnt seem to work right for me. i thought more about like 5 elements in the middle vertical on the sidenav so it looks like an application. they should be more close to each other but i try to fix that :)

Comment: OK i have altered the fiddle